# Kubernetes: Frequently gets "Error adding network: no IP addresses available in network: cbr0"

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, kubeadm

I set up a single-node Kubernetes cluster, using kubeadm, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with flannel.

Most of the time everything works well, but every couple of days, the cluster gets into a state where it can't schedule new pods - the pods are stuck in "Pending" state and When I `kubectl describe pod` of those pods, I error messages like these:

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                SubObjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                -------------   --------    ------      -------
  2m        2m      1   {default-scheduler }                Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned dex-1939802596-zt1r3 to superserver-03
  1m        2s      21  {kubelet superserver-03}            Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "SetupNetwork" for "somepod-1939802596-zt1r3_somenamespace" with SetupNetworkError: "Failed to setup network for pod \"somepod-1939802596-zt1r3_somenamespace(167f8345-faeb-11e6-94f3-0cc47a9a5cf2)\" using network plugins \"cni\": no IP addresses available in network: cbr0; Skipping pod"
```

I've found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41359224/1563935) and the workaround he's suggested. It does help to recover (it takes a several minutes though), but the problem comes back after a while...

I've also encountered this [open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39557), and also got the issue recovered using the suggested workaround, but again, the problem comes back. Also, it's not exactly my case, and the issue was closed after just finding a workaround... :\

Technical details:

```
kubeadm version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6+", GitVersion:"v1.6.0-alpha.0.2074+a092d8e0f95f52", GitCommit:"a092d8e0f95f5200f7ae2cba45c75ab42da36537", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-13T17:03:18Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Kubernetes Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.3", GitCommit:"029c3a408176b55c30846f0faedf56aae5992e9b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-02-15T06:34:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Started the cluster with these commands:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --api-advertise-addresses 192.168.1.200

kubectl taint nodes --all dedicated-

kubectl -n kube-system apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Some syslog logs that may be relevant (I got many of those):

```
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kernel: [  155.480669] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 dockerd[1414]: time="2017-02-23T11:07:49.735590817+02:00" level=warning msg="Couldn't run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/89bb7abdb946d858e175d80d6e1d2fdce0262af8c7afa9c6ad9d776f1f5028c4-init: exec: \"auplink\": executable file not found in $PATH"
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kernel: [  155.496599] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[24704]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 systemd-udevd[29313]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethd4d85eac: No such file or directory
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kubelet[1228]: E0223 11:07:49.756976    1228 cni.go:255] Error adding network: no IP addresses available in network: cbr0
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kernel: [  155.514994] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::835:deff:fe4f:c74d detected!
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kernel: [  155.515380] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kernel: [  155.515588] device vethd4d85eac entered promiscuous mode
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kernel: [  155.515643] cni0: port 34(vethd4d85eac) entered forwarding state
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kernel: [  155.515663] cni0: port 34(vethd4d85eac) entered forwarding state
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kubelet[1228]: E0223 11:07:49.757001    1228 cni.go:209] Error while adding to cni network: no IP addresses available in network: cbr0
Feb 23 11:07:49 server-03 kubelet[1228]: E0223 11:07:49.757056    1228 docker_manager.go:2201] Failed to setup network for pod "somepod-752955044-58g59_somenamespace(5d6c28e1-f8dd-11e6-9843-0cc47a9a5cf2)" using network plugins "cni": no IP addresses available in network: cbr0; Skipping pod
```

Many thanks!

**Edit:**

I am able to reproduce it. It seems like it is an exhaust of the IP addresses in the kubelet CIDR. Findings:

- First, the podCIDR of the node is (got it through `kubectl get node -o yaml`): `podCIDR: 10.244.0.0/24` (BTW, why not /16 as the cluster CIDR I've set in the kubeadm commnad?).
- Second:

  `$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/cni/networks/cbr0 | wc -l`

  `256`  (that is, 256 IPs are assigned, right?)
- But, that happens although I currently have no more than 256 running Kubernetes pods and services:

  `$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces | wc -l`

  `180`

  `### (Yes, this includes not only pods and services, but also jobs, deployments and replicasets)`

So, home comes the IP addresses are exhausted? How to fix that? It can't be that those workarounds are the only ways...

Thanks again.

**Edit (2)**

Another related issue: https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/issues/306

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, this is the best workaround I've found:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34278#issuecomment-254686727

I've set up a cron job to run this script on @reboot.

It seems like that issue has been resolved with a [temp fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/35816) of Garbage Collecting the pods on an event of Docker daemon restart, but that feature was probably not enabled in my cluster.

A few days ago, the new better [long-term fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/37036) was just merged, so I hope this issue will be fixed in the next Kubernetes 1.6.0 release.